# How to add dynamically more than 1 DFP AD Slot to a page after the first one have been rendered?

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I tried to render a dfp ad slot everything I load more content, but for some reason it only render for the first time inside the content.

For all the following loads it does not render.

(you can see problem in here: https://jsfiddle.net/arielvieira96/fLks34q9/2).

```
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        var slot = googletag
          .defineSlot(slotName, slotSize, container.id)
          .addService(googletag.pubads())

        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
          googletag.display(container.id)
          googletag.pubads().refresh([slot])
        })
      })
```

The follwing code for dynamically render the DFP AD Slot only work for the first time

I expected it to render the ad slot everytime more content is loaded, but it only render once.

Comment: Did you have a look at this documentation : https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/4578089?hl=en ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make copies of the creative in the line item you're serving. I'm guessing that there's currently only one. You need to have the same number of creatives as the number of times the /1001352/Centro ad unit will be called per pageload.